# Ordinal response and ordinal predictors

Tags: ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I have recently applied a questionnaire to our students to understand their likelihood to use SCRUM for future projects in their curricula. Most of the predictors and the response variable are 5-point Likert scales.

I would like to understand how to proceed in a regression context. I understand that I might need, for example, to apply an ordinal logistic regression, but how should I treat the predictors? As continuous variables (bias)? With dummies (difficult to interpret, bad coding)?

Is there some particular model suited to this task? I am currently using the `ordinal` package in R to fit a cumulative link model (`clm`), but I am not completely sure it is the best way to proceed (nor do I completely understand the underlying assumptions). Somebody in another thread suggested using `ordPens`, but it seems to ask for a numeric variables (confusing me), while asking for a parameter $\lambda$ that I do not really know how to select (best from a set of options).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right approach using ordinal regression.

The documentation for the `ordinal` package discusses the "proportional odds assumption" somewhat.  See `nominal_test` and `scale_test` [in this document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf), and search for "assumption" [in the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_tutorial.pdf).

I think you can handle the ordinal predictors either way (interval or nominal).  I think for me I would lean towards the interval.  As an experiment, try to translate you 5-point predictors to an interval scale, say 1 to 100.  For most common Likert-type items --- like, Strongly Disagree/D/N/A/SA --- I find that I will translate the categories to, say, 1–20, 21–40, 41–60, 61–80, 81–100. Some Likert-type items won't be like this.  But I think if yours are, it makes sense to treat them as equally-spaced interval data.

Comment: Thanks for your help @sal. If I treat them like equally-spaced interval data, should I recode them? In which way? Or does `ordinal` handle it automatically?

Comment: @jcredberry, the last I looked, the DV for `clm()` and `clmm()` needed to be an ordered category variable.  If your Likert-type responses are coded as numeric, you'll need something like `Data$Likert.f = factor(Data$Likert, ordered = TRUE)`.  For the IV's, if they are already coded as numeric, R should read them as numeric.  If they are factors, `as.numeric(Likert)` will convert them to numeric, but double check the order of the categories first (`levels(Likert)`).  [An example is given here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_11.html) (my own page).