# Logistic regression of both ordinal response and explanatory variables

Tags: logistic, ordinal-data, logit, multinomial-logit, mlogit

[image]

Here the last column is my response variable. I have four predictors that are ordinal. How best to code them to preserve their "ordinal" properties?

Comment: There are a few related posts that may help you, for instance: [Multinomial logit regression with ordinal independent variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70482), [Logistic regression and ordinal independent variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101511), or [Ordinal response and ordinal predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/336890). By the way, there are also posts regarding the [visualization of the relation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56322).

Comment: You can categorize them into the numerical ordering so it might help you with the calculation while building the model from the scratch.